# Showing a specific bound on the derivative of a holomorphic function at fixed point

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:D \to D$ be holomorphic where $D$ is the unit disk and such that $f(1/2)=1/2$. Show $|f'(1/2)| \le 3/4$.

I've used various forms of the Schwarz lemma and Schwarz-pick lemma via composing with the automorphism sending 1/2 to 0, but I'm still only able to prove that $|f'(1/2)| \le 1$ (which it itself is a corollary to Schwarz lemma in my text). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(z) = z$ would appear to be a counterexample.

Comment: I'm going to stick my neck out and say that in fact it _is_ a counterexample...

Comment: lol David $\,\,$